# Include CSV file with more than four columns with csvsimple in Latex document by using MikTex

Tags: csv, latex, miktex

I am using MikTex and want to include CSV tables in my Tex document. I am using the package csvsimple. The following code works fine to include a CSV file with one to three columns.

```
\csvreader[separator=semicolon,late after line=\\\midrule,late after last line=\\\bottomrule]{myfile.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
```

But now I have one more CSV file with four columns.

So I thought I can use:

```
\csvreader[separator=semicolon,late after line=\\\midrule,late after last line=\\\bottomrule]{myfile.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliiii}
```

But it doesn't work. Error message: `Undefined control sequence.` How must I edit the code snippet to include CSV tables with more than three columns?

Thank you.

Comment: It's because you have to use roman numbers, i.e. `iiii` should be `iv`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the entire row of your csv (all columns together) using `\csvlinetotablerow`:

`\csvreader[separator=semicolon,late after line=\\\midrule,late after last line=\\\bottomrule]{myfile.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}`

Comment: So simple. Thanks!